# c++ using random numbers to decide the next encounter

Tags: c++, random, srand

*EDITED for full code*

I am trying to make a text based rpg game because im really bored and want to put my c++ "skills" at test xd.
But i am having a problem with the functions `srand` and `rand`, the function to generate random numbers.

What i want do achieve, is to let the RNG decide the next action of the game. I.e :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "conio.h"
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void GetRandom();

int main()
{
int x;
string name;
srand(time(NULL));

cout << "welcome to adventurers world!" << endl;
cout << "you wake up on an island far far away and you don't know where you are" << endl;
Sleep(2000);
cout << "Please enter the name of your adventurer" << endl;
getline(cin, name);
cout << "hello " << name << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "where would you like to go, " << name << " ?" << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "1. waddle around the beach\n2. go to the cave straight ahead\n3. go into the forest" << endl;
cin >> x;
if(x==1)
{
    cout << "you waddle abit around on the beach, and you suddenly " << random;
}

_getch();
}

void random()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int randnumber = rand() % 2 + 1;
randnumber = randnumber;
if(randnumber == 1)
{
    cout << "you encounter a mudcrab" << endl;
}
else if (randnumber == 2)
{
    cout << "you find a stick" << endl;
}
}
```

What i want do achieve here is, if the random number generated is 1 do (`randnumber == 1`) and if it is 2, do (`randnumber == 2`)
but instead it just gives me a hexidecimal as output.

is my code properly written? am i using the right expression for `srand`, calculation `w/e`.

And is this even possible to do? or do i have to write it out manually what will happen next, which wont make it as much a dynamic game.

thanks for your help and time

Comment: You're not calling your function, you're just evaluating its name.  Try `random()`.

Comment: Calling `srand` once is enough. You don't have to call it each time you want to generate a random number. If you call it fast enough you'll re-seed it with the same number and therefore produce the same "ramdom" numbers again.

Comment: Doing random() solved it. thanks alot.
and i will redo my code so i only call srand once, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, you're not calling the function random, you're displaying its address. Try this:

```
if(x==1)
{
    cout << "you waddle abit around on the beach, and you suddenly ";
    random();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't seed the random generator with the time each time you need a random number.  Unless the usage is a long time between (more than a second), that will set the seed to the same value.
2. Don't name your function `random()`.  That will make the random() function inaccessible.  It probably should be `choose_random_object()` or something like that.
3. Seed the random number generator once when the program begins, and only reseed it if you need to repeat the random numbers (unlikely in a situation such as this).
4. Calling a function should return a value which is useful—which yours is not.  Call a procedure (a function which does not return a value) for its side-effects, such as printing out a word.

Comment: Okay i will note that thanks :)
and what do you mean by the 4th? do i just write return 0; at the end or?

Comment: Good points, +1. What is the `random()` function? Do you mean `rand()` or am I missing something?

Comment: no it was just my own function i called random(), which should calculate what happens next, with the rand() function :P but i renamed it now so its not that "messy" hehe

Comment: @TomFenech:  #include <stdlib.h> on Linux defines `void srandom(int seed);`  to seed the generator; `long int random(void)` to return the next random value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your code should look like. The comments give an explanation of the changes.

```
srand(time(NULL));     // srand() needs only to be called once in the beginning.    

if(x == 1)
{
    cout << "you waddle abit around on the beach, and you suddenly ";
    GetRandom();     // call the function to output what you need.
}

void GetRandom()    // change the name of the function.
{
    int randnumber = rand() % 2 + 1;
    // no need for: randnumber = randnumber;
    if(randnumber == 1)
    {
        cout << "you encounter a mudcrab" << endl;
    }
    else     // no need for else if since the random # cannot be anything else but 2
    {
        cout << "you find a stick" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that definitely helps :) Now i just have another problem. Whenever i run the program, it seems to only output the second option. With the int randnumber = rand() %2 + 1. I made that so it should range from 1-2 and output a random number between 1-2, but it only outputs 2, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: That code should work. I edited my answer, take a look if it solves it.